# Suddenly failing to launch create-react app, giving me module not found and failure to compile message

Tags: reactjs, src

I often get this message even at the beginning when I run my code:

"You attempted to import ______which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/." Did not have this problem before.

What I don't understand if why it happens even when files etc are within src directory? And I have not moved anything. All attempts at doing a React JS project is a fail, as a result.

I considered the issue could be the installation of ESLINT or webconfig as guessed by someone. I am in the very beginning of my code when I get this error message. This happens from all the create-react-app work I do.

This is the code in my App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Layout from './components/Layout/Layout';
import BurgerBuilder from '/containers/BurgerBuilder/BurgerBuilder';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

BurgerBuilder

);
  }
}

export default App;

Comment: check all your imports, atleast 1 of them must be importing something from outside the `src` folder

Comment: Please post code where this happens. Impossible for us to help with details missing. If the project is using React, then you need to make sure React has been installed in your project, and the file accessing it has `import`ed React. If your project has a `package.json` file with `react` in it, then run ''npm install'.  This will create `node_modules` folder and install `react` for you. **Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [Minimal, complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and `edit` your question to community guidelines**

Comment: while doing  npm install put "--save" so that the packages are saved to your project

Comment: Hard to determine where the problem is coming from as this is basically from create-react app where it is failing, in the very beginning.

Comment: Btw, the code above is from one React project I was working on which generated a blank react page. The other one I can post later where I am getting that error. I mixed up both, although they have the same problem of launching from create-react-app. It was never that way before.

Comment: Found the answer. I was running React 15 when I should be running React 16.

Answer (score 0):

This problem apparently occurs if React is an older version (15 in this case when it should be React 16).